# jQuery accordion, minimalistic style - no margin and 1px or no borders

Tags: jquery, border, accordion, margin

First, the margins: there always seem to be a 7px 10px margin of the accordion object to the outside div (even with "fillSpace: true"), and I can't seem to remove them. Is there a way?

Once margin is removed, I'd need the outside border of the accordion completely removed, since the div outside of the accordion is bordered already (or I'd end up with double borders).

Lastly, by default, the accordion has a border surrounding every tab. This means that where two tabs meet, you have double borders, as well as a 1px space in between. The look of this doesn't really appeal to me, so I'd like to remove these 2 borders + 1px space and replace them with a simple 1px border.

Does anyone out there have the knowledge of how to achieve this?

Comment: Edit CSS ? Also visit http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#theming

Comment: My CSS says .ui-accordion { width: 100%; margin: 0; }, but it doesn't do any difference. Any clue?

Comment: Are we talking about jQuery UI's accordion right?

Comment: Yep, that's the one! Do you have any idea of how to solve this? Where is this margin defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Ghokun was right. It's all about the CSS. I couldn't remove the margin earlier since the margin was there simply because of a parent element.